# Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server when using Link element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-bootstrap

I just got started learning `Next.js`, and I came across a component called `<Link/>` for routing between different pages, but I use the `react-bootstrap` library for the `navbar`; this library provides `Nav.Link`, and this component does the same job as `Link` component.

Should I use  *only*  the `Link` or `Nav.Link`? When I tried to put the `Link` inside the `Nav.Link` component, it gives me:

> **Unhandled Runtime Error** Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.

And thank you for your time to read my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Next.js version 13, `Link` is a wrapper around the HTML `<a>` element, as you can read on the official [documentation](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/components/link):

> `<Link>` is a React component that extends the HTML `<a>` element to provide prefetching and client-side navigation between routes. It is the primary way to navigate between routes in Next.js.

And `Nav.Link` from `react-boostrap` render by default an HTML `<a>` as well. So you end up having two nested `<a>`, which is incorrect.

For redirecting in Next.js, prefer using `Link` from Next.js. If you want to use `Nav.Link` from `react-bootstrap` for styling purposes, you could use the `as` property, like so:

```js
<Nav.Link as="span">
  <Link href={"/about"}>About</Link>
</Nav.Link>
```